# Travel insurance for person living in UK but not technically resident

Tags: uk, international-travel, insurance

Many UK travel insurance providers require the policy holder to have lived and been registered with a GP in the UK for at least six months. However, I have only lived in the UK for two months (prior to that I lived in Germany). Some insurance providers say they cover non-UK residents but then ask for another country of residency that is not the UK.

Can anyone recommend any reliable travel insurance that would be available for someone living in the UK but not yet technically resident?

Comment: Do you have German nationality? As far as I know, there are some German travel insurances that do not require a domestic place of residence (and neither do they require a German regular health insurance), so that may be an option.

Comment: @mts - I had to search a bit, and found one. I've added an answer.

Comment: @DCTLib I wasn't aware of this option and this makes for a great and very useful answer not only for the OP. You already have my +1

Answer (score 5):

In case you do not get travel insurance from an insurer in your current country of residence, you may want to have a look if you can find an insurer in your previous country of residence that does not require (a) a domestic place of residence, and (b) a domestic health insurance.

Since you are a former resident of Germany, you may get health insurance from there. Finding a suitable provider can be tricky, as such things tend to be hidden in the fine print. To give you a start, the [ERV](https://www.reiseversicherung.de/de/produktinformationen/jahresversicherung/201406/de/ba-jahres-kv/Wichtige-Infos-VBs2014-Jahres-RK-4005414-0314.pdf) insurance company seems to be fine (according to paragraph 2 of their terms and conditions) with any place of residence in the European Union.

Another possibility would be to get a list of travel health insurance providers and look through their terms and conditions. For example, you should be able to find a whilelist of travel health insurance providers for German applicants for Russian visa on the web.

---

(Note that I only mentioned ERV above because they were the first suitable provider that I could find. The link leads to their T&C document).